# Get column name and type within python sqlite3

Tags: python, sqlite

I am  working with sqlite in python. I want to get column type AND column name in a tuple so that I can work with it.

Eg :

```
CREATE TABLE table(
    A  INTEGER
    B  TEXT
    C  REAL);
```

I know that I can get column names using `sqlite_master` but I cant figure out how to extract column type along with it.

For eg: Get `[(A,INTEGER), (B, TEXT), (C,REAL)]` or anything that has column name and type.

Any help is appreciated.
Thank you

Comment: `c.execute('PRAGMA TABLE_INFO(tablename)')` where `c` is the cursor.

Comment: Thank you! @KlausD. If you could answer I would accept it. It would help a lot more people.